# How can i read a log from a local file in heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have deployed an app on heroku which stores the logs in a local file, is it possible to retrieve/read a single file from heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that I frequently use is to store each log in a database table.

Then, what I do is I take a dump of the database on Heroku which I can then load up on my local machine.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

For moving a backup to a local machine:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

which can then be loaded into a local database.